# VsCode not running on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Hi i am very new to Ubuntu and just installed VsCode and after installing code runner and run my code i keep getting this:

/bin/sh: 1: node: not found

I would very much appreciate some help!

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have `node` installed in your machine. `sudo apt install nodejs` might fix this. Google "Install node on Ubuntu". Or refer [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04)  or any other tutorial you find easy to follow.